# How to get the final axes of a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to get the axes (x, y) from the peak of the plot (the final part of a plot) to show the last amount I get from a COVID prediction in my country.

---

**Code:**

```py
date_pred = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=days_future)
start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%d %b, %Y')
date_pred_str = date_pred.strftime('%d %b, %Y')

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
plt.plot(adjusted_dates, y)
plt.plot(future_forecast_days, svm_prediction, linestyle='dashed', color='red')
plt.title('CODVID-19 30 days prediction', size = 20)
plt.xlabel('30 days prediction', size = 13)
plt.ylabel('Cases', size = 13)
plt.legend([f'Confirmed cases | Growth rate: {round(growth_rate)}%', f'SVM predictions | MAX: {int(round(svm_prediction[-1]))}'])
plt.figtext(x = 0.14, y = 0.72, s = f'from: {start_date_str} \nto:     {date_pred_str}')

plt.figtext(x = 0.78, y = 0.83, s = f'{int(round(svm_prediction[-1]))} -->')
plt.figtext(x = 0.45, y = 0.25, s = f'{int(np.array(df.Confirmed)[-1])} -->')

plt.xticks(size=10)
plt.yticks(size=10)
plt.show()
```

---

**Expected output:**

The idea is to replace x, y in `plt.figtext` from the actual plot or the prediction plot (in here I'm showing just the prediction value):

`plt.figtext(x = x_pred_final, y = y_pred_final, s = f'{int(round(svm_prediction[-1]))} -->')`

`plt.figtext(x = x_actual_final, y = y_actual_final, s = f'{int(np.array(df.Confirmed)[-1])} -->')`

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish and how that's different from what you already have.

Comment: the plot is from a predicton from coronavirus, the last axes from the prediction plot will change across the time when I get new data.